Intel Vtune | analyze linux machine locally via command line | copy and open the results on windoes GUI leads to missing debug symbols
I'm using Intel Vtune to analyze linux machine.
after installign Vtune version l_oneapi_vtune_p_2024.1.0.519_offline.sh I ran the following command via command line:
/tmp/vtune_profiler/vtune/latest/bin64/vtune -collect hotspots -finalization-mode=deferred --duration 10 --target-pid pidof myproc
When copy the result folder to my Windows to be able see the results on Vtune GUI I got:
"can't locate debug symbols for " -> even when i set the symbols dir on the project with the correct debug symbols files.
if the debug symbols are on the target Linux machine during the analyzation so when copy and open on windows it can find the debug symbols (it copying it to the result folder during finalization)
how can I solve or debug the issue to be able set the debug symbols after in my Windows Vtune GUI?
Thanks,
Ben
already tried without successes:

Different Linux machine
Update to the latest Vtune version
Tried use all types of finalization mode (-finalization-mode=deferred/fast/none)


I suggest you just use the VTune web server mode to collect and view your results. All you need is to run a web server on your Linux machine and then you can use all the functionality of the traditional VTune GUI on your laptop in your favorite browser.
Steps:

start the VTune server: <vtune_dir>/bin64/vtune-backend --web-port 8080 --allow-remote-access --enable-server-profiling
copy the provided URL and paste it into your browser's address bar
enjoy

link to the VTune Profiler User Guide: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/vtune-profiler/user-guide/current/web-server-ui.html
